# Sort multidimensonal array with version_compare

Tags: php

How do you sort a multidimensonal array with usort version_compare?

I want to order this array with version_compare based on the version value

```
array(
    array('id' => 1, 'version' => '1.3'),
    array('id' => 2, 'version' => '1.3.1'),
    array('id' => 3, 'version' => '1.3.2'),
    array('id' => 4, 'version' => '1.3.2-RC1'),
    array('id' => 5, 'version' => '1.3.2-RC2'),
);
```

expected order after ordering

1. 1.3.2
2. 1.3.2-RC2
3. 1.3.2-RC1
4. 1.3.1
5. 1.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the comparator with `usort`:

```
usort($arr, function($a,$b) {
    return -1 * version_compare ( $a['version'] , $b['version'] );
});
```

**[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/es1os)**

Read more:

- [version_compare](http://php.net/manual/en/function.version-compare.php)
- [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)

Answer (score 1):

```
usort($a, function($a1, $a2) { return version_compare($a1['version'], $a2['version']); });

$a = array_reverse($a);
```

Should work.

Comment: forgot a `;` and it returns it in reverse