# Sort multidimensonal array by version

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array

Does anyone know how to correctly sort this array by version preserving the sub-arrays.

I have seen similar issues and solutions on stackoverflow but im not able to apply to my array.

Thanks in advance

```
array (size=3)
  '1.23.006' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string '1' (length=1)
  '2.0.0' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string '1' (length=1)
  '10.0.0' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string '1' (length=1)
      1 => string '4' (length=1)
```

I want it to be sorted like this:

```
array (size=3)
  '10.0.0' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string '1' (length=1)
      1 => string '4' (length=1)
  '2.0.0' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string '1' (length=1)
  '1.23.006' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string '1' (length=1)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/how-to-sort-multi-dimensional-array-by-value

Comment: What do you mean by "sort by version"? Which part of the data is the version? What is your expected output?

Comment: Yes i saw that code. But i dont understand it to apply to my array. 1.23.006, 2.0.0, 10.0.0 are the version

Comment: How should the values be sorted? By the first, second and then third parts?

Comment: I have attached how i want it sorted, thank you

Comment: @Fabian thanks for that - but why does `10` sort before `2` and `1`?

Comment: just the top array, the subarrays dont matter

Comment: So it's a descending sort by the version number?

Comment: @Nick because im storing an app build versions as strings and i want to sort them from newer to older version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [`uksort`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php) to sort your array by keys, with a custom function that calls [`version_compare`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.version-compare) to compare them:

```
$data = array('1.23.006' => array('1'), '2.0.0' => array('1'), '10.0.0' => array('1', '4'));

uksort($data, function ($a, $b) {
    return version_compare($b, $a);
});

print_r($data);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [10.0.0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 4
        )
    [2.0.0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
        )
    [1.23.006] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
        )
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/T0GmY)

Comment: But that code will fail if it is "10.0" instead of "10.0.0. " . I also have versions like "10.XX"

Comment: @Fabian I can only answer the question you have asked. Please update the question with **all** the relevant information...

Comment: i want to sort the array by version. bigger to smaller... maybe this code can be applied to my array? but i dont understand it

https://stackoverflow.com/a/48974986/14154823

Comment: @Fabian I've updated the answer to use `version_compare`.

Comment: @Fabian sorry about forgetting that function before; I've never actually used it in the real world. But why did you unaccept the answer?

Comment: @Fabian sorry - I'm not a SOAP expert, so I can't help you with that.